# CSS Horizontal Menu alignment in a cell

Tags: css, alignment, css-tables

I have a CSS Horizontal Menu in a table cell. I have set the cell's alignment to `align=right`.. and the CSS Menu is in that cell but it not right aligned... see the code [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/PGgk8/)... I want to make this menu right aligned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UL is aligning to the right, but it's a block element so that doesn't matter.  Your list elements are floated left within that, which is overriding the alignment.  Float them to the right and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is aligned right.

What you're seeing is the `15px` of padding you put on the right and left sides of the `#menu li a` tags.

Comment: Oooh, my bad. I didn't see a scrollbar on the jsFiddle.